# UV unwrapping wrong but render is correct

Tags: rendering, uv, uv-image-editor

I downloaded the 'Autumn' model from Blender art gallery to render it in my own open-gl-like renderer. This works fine for the body of the dog where uv unwrapping is fine.

But with the 'scarf' object the uv unwrapping behaves strange (see image).

1. Scarf unwrap is not properly aligned to the image texture (scarf is the orange-red scarf-like part of the image) ...
2. ... but the render output of blender is fine. How can that be?

I tried to remove modifiers but that did not help.

Why does blender display the rendered output correctly even if uv unwrap is not aligned?
Moreover: How can I realign the uv unwrap to  match the texture?

Hope anyone smart can help me out.

[image: UV editor and 3D viewport]

Comment: 99% sure that model has several UV Maps.

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@FrederickSteinmetz was right. I exported all objects to a single .obj file in which the currently selected UV map of the 'scarf' object was included. The render instead used an UV Map Node to refer to another UV map.

To resolve the issue I selected the correct map with (Select object -> Object data -> UV maps; Blender 2.80